# bokeh crashes when to much options in select

Tags: bokeh

I am creating some visualization of scientific data, I decided to use bokeh (btw, is the any alternatives, that allow to create controls and plot without so much pain as bokeh?)

I wrote following code:

```
Select(value="Microtubule-associated protein 4",
        title="Protein name:", options=df['Protein Name'].values.tolist()[1:100],
        width=400))  # Sorting nexin-3
```

It works fine, but if I try to pass whole list as options param, it is crashes with error:

```
File "/home/my/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bokeh/core/properties.py", line 1205, in validate
raise ValueError("expected an element of %s, got seq with invalid items %r" % (self, invalid))
ValueError: expected an element of List(Either(String, Tuple(String, String))), got seq with invalid items [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]

print(df['Protein Name'].values.tolist() )  works fine
```

Answer (score 2):

That message is not a case of Bokeh crashing. That message is a validation error, telling you that you are passing invalid data. The message says it fairly directly:

```
expected an element of List(Either(String, Tuple(String, String)))
```

To configure the `options` property for `Select` widget, you must pass either:

- a list of strings: `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`
- or a list of tuples of strings

You are trying to configure the options with something that makes no sense:

```
got seq with invalid items [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

Which is to say, the list of whatever things you are trying to pass in as options contains `NaN` values. This does not, and cannot, make sense, in the context of setting options for a `Select` widget.

If you disagree with this assessment, you'll have to provide more information, e.g. the entire contents of `df['Protein Name'].values.tolist()`

---

As a side comment: Most python libraries will simply fall over with a random exception when bad arguments are passed, Bokeh is somewhat unique in that it provides specific, detailed, and actionable validation errors like this. People work very hard to bring you open source software for free. Perhaps before disparaging that work, you first could take some time to make sure it's not, in fact, a case of user error.

Comment: There was a little missundertanding:

       >>> print(df['Protein Name'].values.tolist())
       ['Sorting nexin-3', 'Uncharacterized protein', 'Tumor-associated        calcium signal transducer 2', '40S ribosomal protein S10', 'Erlin-2']

The select() works fine when I pass df['Protein Name'].values.tolist()[1:100], but if I pass whole list (df['Protein Name'].values.tolist()[1:100]) it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my fault, there was wrong piece of data in list.